# Iterating over query result using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC 5 view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, using Entity Framework 6.

My stored procedure is `sp_caw_pocs` which accepts one parameter and I am accessing the stored procedure in my controller's action method like this:

```
var query = db.sp_caw_pocs(id).ToList();
```

Currently, upon a click event, I am using this stored procedure in an action method with a parameter (Integer), and my query result sometimes returns only 1 or sometimes, 3 items are returned.

I am returning them as a partial result to my view:

```
return PartialView("_CAWPocs", query);
```

The problem I am facing is in my view, where the returned query result, I am not able to iterate over the collection. It is giving the squiggly under the `Model` item.

My view:

```
@model  List<PWBMS.DAL.sp_caw_pocs_Result>
```

Here's the error:

[image]

and the error says

> List<sp_caw_pocs_Result> does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no accessible extension method 'FirstNName' accepting a first argument of type 'List<sp_caw_pocs_Result>' could be found. (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

I am not sure what model I should be using in order to get the result from my ActionResult to iterate over them in the view.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to call the stored procedure in my controller, to pass the list to my view to iterate over?

TIA.

Comment: Does `PWBMS.DAL.sp_caw_pocs_Result` in fact contain those members?

Comment: Side note: if you're using **SQL Server** - you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why are you saying `Model.FirstName` instead of `item.FirstName`?

Comment: @StripplingWarrior, thanks a lot for finding out my typo...i changed it to item.FirstName, and all is well now. Thanks again